# Remove a specific group of inputs in a form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm creating a form in which I need to clone with an "add" button a complete group/section of fields in my form, and also I need to delete them with a "delete" button.
The "add" button works perfectly, it means when I click add the complete group of fields are added correctly. But, when I click the "delete" button it remove all cloned group or the last one, and what I want to do is that if a click on the delete button of the second cloned group and there are five groups the second is deleted and not the last one or all cloned groups.

The HTML that I have is the following:

```
<div id=firstform>
<div class="card">
   <label class="label-nuevo-oficio" id="label-title">
       Title
   </label>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" id="delete">
       delete 
   </button>
   <div>
     <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tipoSolicitud" id="auth" value="yes">
     <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">Autorización</label>
     </div>
     <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tipoSolicitud" id="update" value="no">
     <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Actualización</label>
     </div>
     <label class="label-requis numero-oficio" id="label-numero-oficio">
            Number Oficio
     </label></br>
     <input class="form-control" type="text" name="num-oficio[]">
     <label class="label-requis fecha-emision" id="fecha-emision">
            Date
     </label></br>
     <input class="form-control" type="date" aria-label="default input example">
     <label class="label-requis fecha-tesoreria" id="fecha-tesoreria">
            Birthday
     </label></br>
     <input class="form-control" type="date" aria-label="default input example">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" id="add">
       delete 
     </button>
   </div>
</div> 
</div>
<div id="new-form"></div>
```

For the add function that works correctly I implement the following using jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('button[id="add"]').on('click', function() {
        $('#firstform .card') 
            .clone(true, true)
            .attr('id', 'cloned_t')

            //To clone it empty  
            .find("input:text").val("").end()
            .find('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', false).end()
            .find('input[type=date]').val('00-00-0000').end()
            .find('input[type=number]').val('0.0').end()
            
            .appendTo('#new-form');
    });
});
```

For the delete function I've tried many things, but I always return to this which is basically what I have accomplished until now:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('button[id="delete"]').on('click', function delete() {
        $("#new-form .card").remove();   
    });
});
```

But I've also tried with

```
$("#new-form .card").last().remove();
```

I'm wowndering if there's a function like .last() but that delete the specific clone section that I want to delete. Or if there's a way to put a different id for every cloned gorup. Or can someone help me to solve this problem with another solution.

Again, the problem is that when I add 5 groups, for example, and I want to delete the third group every cloned group is deleted or just the last one.

Thank you.

Comment: You should use DOM navigation relative to `$(this)` to refer to the card that contains the delete button, e.g. `$(this).closest(".card").remove()`

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique. Use classes for elements that you duplicate.